# Multiple tables with same class in Room database

Tags: android, android-room

I have two table named "PostHis", "PostLike" with same structure:

`kotlin
    @Entity data class Post(...)`

Is there any way to handle that?

---

the bad way is:

`kotlin
    @Entity data class PostHis:Post(...)
    @Entity data class PostLike:Post(...)`

Comment: Do you still need to know how to create multiple tables ? Or did you solve it ?

Comment: @FarhanIbnWahid in a similar situation. Could you share what you had in mind?